# BIOS INT13h AH=42h with BOCHS

Tags: assembly, bios, osdev, bochs

I got trouble with my bootloader code. I try to use the INT 13h AH=42h: "Extended Read Sectors From Drive" BIOS function of version 3.0 (EDD-3.0) with BOCHS to copy my kernel code from a hard disk image to a memory location above 0x100000 in real mode.

When I use the INT13 AH=41h BX=55AAh function to check for support of EDD-3.0 I get a positive result. I'm using BOCHS 2.6.8.

```
Disk Address Packet:
db  0x1C    ; size of packet (I tried 18h as well)
db  0x00    ; reserved
db  0x04    ; # blocks to transfer
db  0x00    ; reserved
dw  0xFFFF  ; offset
dw  0xFFFF  ; segment
dq  0x1     ; starting absolute block number (LBA)
dq  0x100000; 64-bit flat target address
```

I use this DAP. What BOCHS does is copy 4 blocks from disk to FFFF:FFFF mod 100000h = FFEFh. What am I doing wrong?
I use Ralf Brown's Interrupt List (http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0708.htm) as reference.

Comment: "size of packet" does not seem to match what RBIL says???

Comment: You are right, I also tried 0x18h but it doesn't work. So it seems that this is not the problem.

Comment: Since you're trying to write to a location above 0x1000000, I'm wondering what you've done in real mode to make that accessible... :)

Comment: Thats the point: in real mode I'm unable to move code or data to a location above FFFFFh so thats why I tried to get help from BIOS. There are functions which should support that like the INT 13h AH=42h function mentioned above, but it seems like you can not rely on their existence or complete implementation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old BIOSs did not support the "extended disk bios" functions at all.

Later BIOSs did not support all the features that the latest BIOS versions have.

I'm sure that even some modern BIOSs do not support "flat target addresses" but only the segment:offset addresses - and the segment:offset field in your structure is 0xFFFF:0xFFFF.

Such BIOSs will recognize the address 0xFFFF:0xFFFF then.

Maybe the BIOS in the BOCHS emulator is of that kind.

BTW: I had a computer where the function did not work correctly if the ES register was not identical to the segment given in the control packet!

Some other things that may not work with some BIOSs are overflows in the offset part (reading N bytes to address A:B so that (B+N)>0x10000) as well as accessing memory above 0x100000 ((0x10*A+B+N)>0x100000).

Comment: Thx for your answer. Seems like the error is to rely on what INT13h AH=41h BX=55AAh returns. I thought that BOCHS has a "clean" implemented BIOS with reliable functionality. I will look for another solution...

Comment: It turned out that RBIL for INT13h AH=42h is not correct/up-to-date. There is a fourth bit set in register CX after a call to INT13h AH=41h BX=55AAh if support for 64-bit flat addresses is implemented. RBIL doesn't mention this but this paper does: http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2004/d1572r3-EDD3.pdf
Thx for your help.

Comment: Do note that most BIOSes don't implement the EDD3 extensions.